# Bound on the expectation of a function of random variable having a strictly log-concave probability density

Tags: posterior, bounds, tail-bound, log-concave

let $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be a random variable having a strictly log-concave probability density function, i.e
\begin{equation}
p(\theta) = e^{-\phi(\theta)}
\end{equation}
where $\phi(\theta)$ is a strictly convex function. $p(\theta)$ is an intractable distribution (contains an intractable integral) I can only compute $\hat{\theta}_{mode}$, and using the Brascamp-Lieb inequality I could bound the covariance of $\theta$ by:
\begin{equation}
Cov(\theta) \preceq  \mathbb{E}_{\theta \sim p(\theta)}[\phi^{''}(\theta)]
\end{equation}
$\phi^{''}(\theta)$ being the hessian of $\phi(\theta)$. Now I need to upper bound the expectation of the form:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}_{\theta \sim p(\theta)}[f(\theta)]
\end{equation}is there any way I could arrive to a meaningful upper bound that is not simply an upper bound on $f(\theta)$?

I was thinking since the tails of a log-concave measure are sub-Gaussian, one could construct a Gaussian approximation around the mode with some sort of a variance inflation factor to the covariance to ensure that the confidence sets of the Gaussian are super-sets of the intractable distribution, and then have a probabilistic bound. I wasn't sure how to achieve that.